# Changing default save location in IDLE 3.9.13 (app) on Windows 11

Tags: python-idle

I'm trying to change the default save location for IDLE 3.9.13 on Windows 11.

The answers I've seen say to locate it in the search window, then right-click and open the file location, then change the default location in 'properties'.

However the version I have installed doesn't have this option to open the location, that's only there in versions 3.7 and previous.

I thought initially that installing IDLE 3.11 from the Python.Org website would probably fix this, however when I've pasted in the directory into which I want it to save, it's defaulting to:

```
C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311
```

rather than the:

```
C:\Users\x\OneDrive\Documents\Python project files
```

that I've changed it to, even though the "start in" directory seems to have changed.

Hope someone can help :)

Comment: I just changed the `Start in:` directories for the IDLE shortcuts for 3.10 and 3.11 and it worked fine.  `^O` for Open file opened in the new directory.  Perhaps there is some problem starting in a OneDrive directory.  Try something else.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, thanks very much - I'm old, I started using computers before Windows 3.1. I still don't get why my entire Desktop all of a sudden needs to be in the cloud....!

Answer (score 0):

Solution: uninstalled Python 3.11, installed using `custom` installation: changed install directory to `c:\users\x\` - now works as expected.

Comment: I spoke too soon - it's changed it to ```System32``` now for reasons of its own.
Never mind.